# Rails timestamps use int (unixtime) rather than DATETIME for updated_at and created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to set Rails to record unix timestamp (stored as INT) as opposed to regular DATETIME fields for updated_at and created_at?

These are defined via:

```
t.timestamps
```

in migration file.

NOTE: I don't want to convert it to unix timestamp, I want it STORED as unixtime stamp in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make `t.timestamps` to create the pair with anything other than `datetime` because the datatype is [hardcoded](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c7a1fa364012c70e76d19b36881c9bde016091b8/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L862-L863).

Note however that ActiveRecord doesn't really care that much about the underlying type. If you create these fields manually with the integer datatype (or convert an existing table) and edit/create a record, ActiveRecord will attempt to set the values with `Time.zone.now` (or `Time.now` depending on your `default_timezone` setting) but the value will be automatically converted into integer right after.

The downside is that AR will not convert the value back to a datetime so if you want to store the values as integers but work with them as if they were datetimes, you need to do the conversion manually.